# No Rest Between Cycling And Running

Tags: running, bicycling

is this ok if i don't take rest between cycling and running activities ... here is my routine

1. first five days : running ( 30 - 35 km )
2. sat,sun : cycling ( 80 - 100    km )

Answer (score 2):

Recovery is important. You should have at least 1 day a week without any exercise (or at most some gentle yoga/walking).

Comment: ok . what if do running in first 4 days then take rest on friday
and do cycle + running on sat and only cycling on sun

Comment: That's fine, so long as you are getting enough sleep and food.